# Restrict SELECT width to width of parent TH

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I generate filter SELECTs and INPUTs to the footer TH of my data table. I want these items widths to match width of parent TH (minus some margin).

My TH elements have classes *.datainput* or *.dataselect* to know, whether SELECT or INPUT should be generated.

I've created this script, which is called after AJAX data are loaded and inputs are generated:

```
function fnFixElementsTH() {

  // Fix data inputs
  $('.datainput').each(function(i) {
    var thWidth = $(this).width(); 
    $(this).children().width(thWidth); 
  }); 

  // Fix data selects
  $('.dataselect').each(function(i) {
    var thWidth = $(this).width() - 10; 
    $(this).children().width(thWidth); 
  });   
}
```

I use following CSS for TH:

```
padding: 3px 0px 3px 10px;
font-weight: bold;
font-weight: normal;
```

And for select:

```
word-wrap: normal;
margin-right: 10px;
```

In chromium it is working perfectly:
[image: chromium]

But in firefox, SELECTs have invalid sizes:
[image: firefox]

I printed widths of THs and SELECTs in chromium and firefox and here are the results for second column in chromium:

[image: chromium2]

And in firefox:

[image: firefox2]

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong, or suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in .width() Jquery API. It has some issue with FF. You can use .css to set the width.

```
  $(".dataselect").each(function(i) {
    var thWidth = $(this).width() - 10; 
    $(this).children().css('width',thWidth); 
  });
```

Solution Fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/vfNRS/1](http://www.jsfiddle.net/vfNRS/1)

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle.It would be easy to solve the problem

Comment: Thank you, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/gZEc9/11/  in chromium selects are nice and centered, however in firefox they are move to the right

Comment: You need to use the CSS instead of .width(). It has some problem in FF. Checkout the solution fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vfNRS/1/

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution, outer width of select has to be set:

```
// Fix data selects
$('.dataselect').each(function(i) {
  var thWidth = $(this).width() - 10; 
  //$(this).children().width(thWidth);     THIS WAS WRONG
  $(this).children().outerWidth(thWidth);
});
```

Solution is here: http://jsfiddle.net/gZEc9/12/